# Javascript append to a specific place in an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, math

I'm building a keypad to enter monetary amounts via touch device.

http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/hrEmK

Once the user has entered 2 digits, I append a decimal. However, once they enter 4 digits, I need to carry the decimal over so it's always 2 digits from the end of the string of numbers.

This way the string always appears as dollars and cents.

I've not been able to find a way to .append X digits from the end of the string in #numBox. Also, even if I was able to, there would need to be someway to search the string for the old decimal and remove it before adding another one digit over to the right.

Any help? Happy to explain further if this isn't concise. Be patient, I'm a total SO noob.

Comment: While these methods work, from a UX (user experience) point of view they have a MAJOR draw back.  Lets say I mean to enter `13` but I type `12` but accident.  SO, I hit the keys `1` for the first digit, `3` for the second. At this point a decimal point appears.  Hitting `delete` now erases the decimal point I didn't type and I finish off by hitting `2` then `enter`.  I now have the value of `132` instead of `12` in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue

```
if (digits %2 == 0) 
{
      var mystring = $( "#numBox" ).html();
      mystring = mystring.replace('.','');
      $( "#numBox" ).html(mystring);
      $( "#numBox" ).append(".");
      console.log("worked!");
}
```

Check the updated code on http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/hrEmK

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var digits = 0; 
  var numBox = document.getElementById('numBox');




    $('.key').click(function(){


        if(this.innerHTML == '0'){
            if (numBox.innerHTML.length > 0)
                numBox.innerHTML = numBox.innerHTML + this.innerHTML;
                digits += 1;
                //console.log("digits");

        }
        else
            // add digits          
            numBox.innerHTML = numBox.innerHTML + this.innerHTML;
            digits += 1;
            //console.log(digits);

        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.btn').click(function(){
        if(this.innerHTML == 'DEL'){
            var numBox = document.getElementById('numBox');
            if(numBox.innerHTML.length > 0){

                // delete a digit
                numBox.innerHTML = numBox.innerHTML.substring(0, numBox.innerHTML.length - 1);
                digits -= 1;
                //console.log(digits);
            }
        }
        else{

            // clear numbox
            document.getElementById('numBox').innerHTML = '';
            digits = 0;
            //console.log(digits);
        }

        event.stopPropagation();
        _checkForDecimals();
    });


    //decimal entry

    $('.key').click(function(){

    _checkForDecimals();

 });

  function _checkForDecimals()
  {
   if (digits > 2) {
      var mystring = $( "#numBox" ).html();
      mystring = mystring.replace('.','');
      var firstPartOfString = mystring.slice(0, mystring.length - 2);
      var secondPartOfString =  mystring.slice( mystring.length - 2,mystring.length);
      //alert(firstPartOfString+'.'+secondPartOfString)
      mystring = firstPartOfString+'.'+secondPartOfString;
      $( "#numBox" ).html(mystring);
      //$( "#numBox" ).append(".");
      console.log("worked!");
    } 
  }

});
```

Comment: I updated the code here: http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/hrEmK but it's still not working correctly. I need the decimal to always be exactly 2 digits from the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry , my bad , I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        var str = "12.345";
        str= str.replace("\.","");
        if(str.length > 2){
            str = str.substr(0, str.length - 2) + '.' + str.substr(str.length - 2);
        }
        alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your fix.But it seems to have an issue.If you press all the keys from 1 to 9, the number becomes 12345678.9. But as per your requirement it should have been 1234567.89 [if I understood correctly].
Please try the below solution and see if it fits your requirement. Please note, at the end of the code block I've added two functions "GetNumberAfterAppendingDecimal" and "GetCleanString" and I've used then on  $(.key).click();

```
$('.key').click(function(){
 var inputNumber=GetCleanString($("#numBox").html());

 $("#numBox").html(GetNumberAfterAppendingDecimal(inputNumber));
```

});

```
 function GetNumberAfterAppendingDecimal(str) {
    if (str.length < 3)
        return str;
    var positionFromEnd = 2;
    var reversedStr = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    if (str.length == 3)
        positionFromEnd -= 1;
    reversedStr = [reversedStr.slice(0, positionFromEnd), ".", reversedStr.slice(positionFromEnd)].join('');
    return reversedStr.split('').reverse().join('');
}
function GetCleanString(str) {
str = str.replace(/[\r]+/, '');
str = str.replace(/[\n]+/, '');
str = str.replace(/[\t]+/, '');
str = str.replace('.', '');
str = $.trim(str);
return str;
}
```

Comment: In case of 3 digits, for example 123, if you want output as 1.23, then remove following condition from the function "GetNumberAfterAppendingDecimal":if (str.length == 3)
        positionFromEnd -= 1;

Comment: thanks so much! The only problem now is that if you use the delete button, the decimal looses it's place again. Would you be so kind as to help me make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just repleat the code inside $(.key).onclick() for $(div.btn).onclick()..see below :

```
 $('div.btn').click(function(){


 var inputNumber=GetCleanString($("#numBox").html());

 $("#numBox").html(GetNumberAfterAppendingDecimal(inputNumber));

 });
```